# Epic-monic factorisation in $\mathbf{Set}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, alternative-proof

I'm stuck on [Exercise 5.2.1](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hLPDAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA461&lpg=PA461&dq=%22images+of+arrows%22+topoi+goldblatt&source=bl&ots=qRfIG2WRNa&sig=pzYaksKUYphV_Xf3WpiuVW0PaIU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rCinU6XSFaKt0QW-7oG4Ag&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22images%20of%20arrows%22%20topoi%20goldblatt&f=false) of Goldblatt's "*Topoi: A Categorial Analysis of Logic*":

> Given a function $f:A\to B$, if $h\circ g: A\twoheadrightarrow C\rightarrowtail B$ and $h'\circ g': A\twoheadrightarrow C'\rightarrowtail B$ are two different epic-monic factorisations of $f$ (i.e. $f=h\circ g=h'\circ g'$), then there exists a unique $k:C\to C'$ such that
>
> [image]
>
> commutes, and furthermore $k$ is iso in $\mathbf{Set}$.

The rest of the section seems okay. It gives a categorical proof in any topos. However, **I'd like a set-theoretic proof please**.

I've tried defining $k: C\to C'$ by way of equivalence classes; namely, by letting $k(c)=g'(\gamma)$ for some $\gamma$ with $c=g(\gamma)$, so that since $g$ in onto, I can iron out any ambiguity by saying $\gamma\sim_{g}\delta$ iff $g(\gamma)=g(\delta)$, then go from there. (Do you see what I mean?) I can't get it to work.

Please help :)

Comment: $k = (h')^{-1}\circ h$. Since $h'$ is injective, $(h')^{-1}$ is well-defined on $f(A)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, yes; of course! Thank you :)

Comment: @DanielFischer Would you like to extend on that and post it as an answer? I made a slight *faux pas*. Sorry :)

Comment: I've edited the answer, should be fine now. (Yay for CW).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the context of binary *relations* for a clear proof.

Let $r$ be a relation between $A$ and $B$, i.e. $r\subseteq A\times B$ (or $r:A\times B\to\{false,\ true\}$ if you prefer), and let $\def\inv{^\smallsmile} r\inv$ denote the inverse relation $\subseteq B\times A$. Using infix notation, it means that
$$a\mathop rb\iff b\mathop{r\inv}a\,.$$
Also, define $r\le r'$ iff $r\subseteq r'$ as sets, i.e. $r(a,b)\Rightarrow r'(a,b)$ for all $a\in A,\,b\in B$.

Let me write composition of relations from left to right and $1_A$ for the equality relation on set $A$.

Verify that for a relation $f\subseteq A\times B$ we have that

1. $f$ is a 'partial function' ($a\mathop fb,\,a\mathop fb'\implies b=b'$)$\,$ iff $\ f\inv f\le 1_B$
2. $f$ is 'everywhere defined'$\,$ iff $\ ff\inv\ge 1_A$
3. $f$ is 'injective' iff $\ f\inv$ is a partial function, i.e. $\ ff\inv\le 1_A$
4. $f$ is 'surjective' iff $\ f\inv$ is everywhere defined, i.e. $\ f\inv f\ge 1_B$.

Thus in our situation, we have $g\inv g=1_C=hh\inv$ and the same way, $g_1\inv g_1=1_{C'}=h_1h_1\inv$.

Now $k:=g\inv g_1$. This also equals to $hh_1\inv$ because
$g\inv g_1h_1=g\inv f=g\inv gh=h $, so 
$g\inv g_1=g\inv g_1h_1h_1\inv=h\,h_1\inv$.

Finally, $k\inv=g_1\inv g$ and we can easily check that $kk\inv=1_C$, and by the same argument, $k\inv k=1_{C'}$, which proves that $k$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

Since $h'$ is injective, the inverse $(h')^{-1}$ is well-defined on $f(A) = h'(C')$.

Therefore we can set $k = (h')^{-1}\circ h$.

Comment: What is the purpose of this "answer"?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I [read in the meta site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-should-one-do-when-ones-question-has-been-answered-in-the-comments) that if a question is answered in the comments, then it's acceptable to say so in a community wiki answer (which is then accepted). It takes it off the list of unanswered questions :)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I welcome more answers (of course). I suppose it would have been better to ask Daniel Fischer to post the answer himself too. I'll do that next time :)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg The purpose of the *set-theoretic* answer is to contrast it with the categorical one under the advice Goldblatt :)