# Arrows-only implication & disjunction in $\mathbf{Set}.$

Tags: logic, category-theory, intuition, topos-theory

Just before the [truth-arrows in a topos](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hLPDAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=%22truth-arrows+in+a+topos%22&source=bl&ots=qRfIL0ZMMd&sig=-mbX2gcXHJH8vbmu08HO7OOUbqI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aYWuU-XHEIKp7Abot4CoDQ&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22truth-arrows%20in%20a%20topos%22&f=false) subsection of Goldblatt's "*Topoi: A Categorial Analysis of logic,*" descriptions of the **truth functions** $\Rightarrow$ and $\smallsmile$ are given in $\mathbf{Set}$ in terms of arrows. This is to motivate their abstraction to any given topos.

> I'm having trouble understanding these descriptions *thoroughly*, so I would like some clarification, please :)

**Definition 1:** The *disjunction truth-function* $\smallsmile :2\times 2\to 2$ (for $2=\{0, 1\}$) is given by $1\smallsmile 1=0\smallsmile1=1\smallsmile0=1$ and $0\smallsmile0=0$, whereas the *implication truth-function* $\Rightarrow: 2\times 2\to 2$ is given by $1\Rightarrow0=0$ and $(0\Rightarrow1)=(0\Rightarrow0)=(1\Rightarrow1)=1$.

**Definition 2:** $\smallfrown$ can be taken as the characteristic function of the product map $\langle\operatorname{true}, \operatorname{true}\rangle$.

---

**Implication.**

Goldblatt states that $\Rightarrow$ is the characteristic function of [image]$=\{\langle 0, 0\rangle,\langle 0, 1\rangle, \langle 1, 1\rangle\}$ with

[image]

a pullback square, which he then uses to write [image] as the equaliser of $\smallfrown:2\times 2\to 2$ and $pr_1$, where $pr_1(\langle x,y\rangle)=x$. *I don't see how he does this.*

---

**Disjunction:**

We take $\smallsmile$ as $\chi_D$ for $D=A\cup B$ for $A=\{\langle1, 1\rangle, \langle1, 0\rangle\}$ and $B=\{\langle1, 1\rangle,\langle0, 1\rangle\}$; identify $A$ with the product map $\langle\operatorname{true}_2, 1_2\rangle$, $B$ with $\langle1_2, \operatorname{true}_2\rangle$; form the coproduct map $f=[\langle\operatorname{true}_2, 1_2\rangle, \langle1_2, \operatorname{true}_2\rangle]$; identify $\operatorname{im} f=D$; [epic-monic factor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844575/epic-monic-factorisation-in-mathbfset) $f$ through $D$; then claim that all this specifies $D$ - and hence $\small\smile$ - uniquely up to isomorphism.

> So yeah, I can't see the wood for the trees basically. Please help :)

Comment: Okay, things are starting to make sense . . .

Comment: Ah, I get it. **It's easy!** I'm overthinking it. I'll type up my answer tomorrow :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was trying too hard.

**Implication.**

When Goldblatt used the lattice equivalence $$x\sqsubseteq y \iff x=x\sqcap y$$ to write [image] as $$\{\langle x, y\rangle\vert x\smallfrown y=x\},$$ he did so for a reason: it's so that [image] is the set for which $\smallfrown$ and $pr_1$ agree, which is then, by [$\S 3.10$](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hLPDAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=goldblatt+topoi+%22equaliser%22&source=bl&ots=qRfJEYWQQb&sig=RGop1pIBE1jZIazyZ_LYkA5NvdE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=B3OyU-f-AcOeO5vlgcAI&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=goldblatt%20topoi%20%22equaliser%22&f=false), the equaliser of the two.

**Disjunction.**

If you draw the commutative diagrams for the products $t_1=\langle\operatorname{true}_2=\operatorname{true}\circ\vert_2, 1_2\rangle$ and $t_2=\langle1_2,\operatorname{true}_2\rangle$ and write down all the equations (like $pr_2\circ t_1=1_2$), you'll see that $t_1$ and $t_2$ are nothing more than what Goldblatt said they were: $t_1$ sends $0$ to $\langle1, 0\rangle$ and $1$ to $\langle1, 1\rangle$; $t_2$, similarly; and we can identify them with $A$ and $B$, respectively, because $A$ and $B$ are two-element sets whose set-inclusions with respect to $2\times 2$ are $t_1$ and $t_2$, respectively.

The coproduct $2+2$ is just the disjoint union of $2$ with itself, so that we can write $$2+2=2^{(0)}\cup2^{(1)},$$ where $2^{(0)}=2\times\{0\}$ and $2^{(1)}=2\times\{1\}$, to see that $f$ is given by $$f(a, i)=\begin{cases}t_1(a) &: i=0 \\ t_{2}(a) &: i=1.\end{cases}$$

The rest is downhill from there (once you see that $\operatorname{im}f=\operatorname{im}t_1\cup\operatorname{im}t_2$).